# Real rings with a zero divisor

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. We say that $A$ is a real ring if every sum of squares of non-zero elements of $A$ is not zero. It is well-known that if $A$ is a real ring and an integral domain, then the quotient field of $A$ is an orderable field. My question:
Give an example of a real ring which is not integral domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a direct product of real rings, for example $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ is good example for your question.$(1,0).(0,1)=(0,0)$